# Use Django model from another app and create entries in independent database table

Tags: python, django, database

I have two Django applications, as illustrated below. As is, Django will create two DB tables, 'appa_modela' and 'appb_modelb'. ModelB objects created by commA.py will be saved to the 'appb_modeb' table. However, I'd like ModelB objects created by appA to be independent of those created by appB. I am aware of the 'Meta' subclass, where 'app_label' and 'db_table' are set. How could one ensure that 'app_label' is changed to be 'appA' when ModelB is imported into an appA module?

appA/models.py

```
from django.db import models
class ModelA(models.Model):
  list_of_modelB_pk = models.TextField(default='',
       validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])
```

appA/management/commands/commA.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import json
from appA.models import ModelA
from appB.models import ModelB
class Command(BaseCommand):
  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    mb1 = ModelB()
    mb1.save()
    print mb1._meta.app_label # prints 'appB' why not 'appA'?
    mb2 = ModelB()
    mb2.save()
    ma = ModelA()
    ma.list_of_modelB_pk = json.dumps([mb1.pk,mb2.pk])
    ma.save()
    print ma._meta.app_label # prints 'appA'
```

appB/models.py

```
from django.db import models
class ModelB(models.Model):
  fieldB1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

appB/manangement/commands/commB.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from appB.models import ModelB
class Command(BaseCommand):
  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    mb1 = ModelB()
    mb1.save()
    mb2 = ModelB()
    mb2.save()
```

Comment: Subclass the model in the other application.

Comment: You mean in appA/models.py import ModelB and create something like **class LocalModelB(ModelB): pass**.